# NodeJs unexpected crashing issues - how to handle

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am new to NodeJs development. In our project I have come across 2 situations where the nodejs server crashes, without coming to the catch in the try/catch or coming to the if (err) callback. (In Java it would always come to the catch, so we can handle it)

1. I use 'extract-zip' and in this line it crashes for certain files created from our system, as it seems to contain an extra slash before the file name inside the zip. Here is the code part for that and this is inside a try catch

```js
 extract(filePath, { dir: extractFiledir }, function (err) {
          if (err) {}
```

It crashes the server with `events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`
saying 'Error: invalid characters in fileName: images\aa.jpg'

2. I am using formidable to read a uploaded file. If I call that web service without attaching a file, again server crashes after some time giving the `events.js:174` error above with
   'Error: Request aborted
   at IncomingMessage. (xxx\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:122:19)'

```js
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req);
```

My question is how can we handle such errors, without letting a server crash to happen. Please let me know what I am missing here. May be I am missing something in NodeJs related to such error handling, which I am not aware of.

**UPDATE :**  I was able to get the issue 2 fixed by using callback like this

```
form.parse(req, (error, fields, files) => {
                if (error) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    //continue if no error
                }
            });
```

But the issue 1 doesn't come to the error even when added like this.

```
  extract(filePath, { dir: extractFiledir }, (err)  => {
          if (err) {
            return;
          } else {}
```

Comment: It would helpful if you can post the main code which calls these methods or lines.

Comment: @AshishModi Please see my update above. For the issue one, I am uploading a zip file using formidable and parse it as in the sample code above and then call the extract function in extract-zip. It crashes at that line for certain zips created with certain data. But it works fine for other zip files. My issue is how to handle that error without crashing the server, since it doesn't come to that if (err) condition. Thank you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-zip